# Visual Studio 2010 Premium SP1 Very Annoying Typing Lag

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance

I've recently noticed that after my projects grow a certain size I end up getting a lot of VERY annoying typing lag in VS2010.  It affects every language and every word I type ends up taking around 5 seconds to render - the same with deletes, it also buffers them well enough as if I become unreasonably impatient and hit delete again 3 seconds later... it processes ALL my deletes.

So the obvious point is hardware: Intel Core2 6300 @ 1.87GHz, 2GB RAM, 32-bit OS and a usual 7200rpm 8MB cache HDD, shouldn't experience this much lag surely!  So I've decided to uninstall and re-install VS2010 to remove any plugins I may be using (the only one I personally installed was AnkhSVN for Subversion).  Still the exact same problem.

Where I'm up to now, I've just attached a debugger to view the native code of my devenv.exe process and I see that every character I type throws a huge number of these **First-chance exception at 0x757ed36f in devenv.exe: 0xE0434352: 0xe0434352.** - anybody have any idea what this is / how I can find the source of these offsets?

Comment: Just a review - have noticed that these exceptions are mostly thrown while in a *.cshtml / *.aspx source view... is there a problem when it's trying to synch with the design view do you think?

Comment: I just started experiencing the same issue. It seems like it happens mainly when I edit .cshtml pages. Did you find the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same issue when editing .cshtml files in Visual Studio 2010. At first I thought it was a memory issue, but MemTest showed no errors and it was a very isolated problem within Visual Studio, so I looked elsewhere.

I searched through some forums and got the idea to look at Extensions I had installed. For me, the only one that pertained to editing CSS/HTML that I was running was [Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f?SRC=VSIDE). I uninstalled it and restarted the IDE, and the lag was gone.

It is strange because I have been running this extension for awhile in multiple environments and never experienced any issues. I'm not sure what changed or why it broke, but for anyone having this problem, look at the extensions you have installed.

I have also heard a lot of people having issues with the [CSS3/HTML5 Web Standards Update](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83) extension. I didn't have it installed but it might cause similar issues.

Comment: Interesting... I looked but couldn't see any extensions that may cause the problem.  Nevertheless I did a complete fresh install of visual studio on my 2nd dev box, exact same problem?!?!  Very annoying, guess we just wait for a direct / indirect fix from Microsoft.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like there is no silver bullet for this issue. Found some other forum posts (http://bit.ly/GNoBhk) that point to problems with MVC4. Did you install the new beta of MVC4? Can you try editing files in ASP.NET MVC 3 and see if there is a difference?

Comment: Hmm not really looked into MVC4 but will certainly try this and get back as soon as I get the time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue in VS2012.  After reading mhornfeck's answer I tried uninstalling the following via Add/Remove Programs then restarting VS:

- Microsoft Office Visual Web Developer 2007. Product Version: 12.0.4518.1066.
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages. Product Version: 1.0.20105.0.

And the lag is gone!